# Python FTP TLS not working

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to setup an FTP TLS transfer.  I have scripts for strict FTP and for SFTP, but this is my first exposure to TLS.  My basic script:

```
import ftplib
import ssl

ctx = ssl._create_stdlib_context(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS(context=ctx)

print (ftps.connect(myhost,21))
print(ftps.login(myusername,mypwd))
print("1")
ftps.prot_p()
print("2")
print (ftps.retrlines('LIST'))
print("3")
```

Error:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This error occurs at the retrlines line.  It says the error is in ssl.py at do_handshake `self._sslobj.do_handshake()`.

I've already verified the connection with `WinSCP`, and that the protocol is `TLS1.2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue turned out to be that the vendor was only allowing access from a specific machine.  Once I tried the script on the correct machine, it worked.